# How can i choose an Authentication Mode If i do not have permits?

Tags: sql-server

I can start SQL SERVER only with Windows Authentication mode. I want to change to mixed mode. I tried the following:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the
   server, and then click Properties.
2. On the Security page, under Server    authentication, select the new
   server authentication mode, and then click OK.
3. In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to
   acknowledge the requirement to restart SQL Server.
4. In Object    Explorer, right-click your server, and then click
   Restart. If SQL    Server Agent is running, it must also be
   restarted.

In second step I get an error:

[image]

I do not have permissions to make the changes. My account does not have the right to carry out the change. I tried to assign to my login sysadmin but it failed.
It tells me:

[image]

What should I do? Should I reinstall and configure authentication on mixed mode?

Comment: If you are a windows admin on the machine (I assume you are, because you mention reinstalling the instance), restart the service in single user mode, this will give you sysadmin perms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You donot need to reinstall SQL Server instance. Instead follow below given steps

1]Change registry as follows

"Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLEXPRESS\LoginMode" = 2

2]Once you change value in registry,follow below given URL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx